# reboot with lag time between shutdown and startup

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to reboot a machine running ubuntu 18, but having a wait time between shutdown and startup?

e.g. I want to shutdown at 8pm and have it automatically start up at 8am

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the OS does not support Automatic Boot. It's logical since it's a hardware issue. However, many BIOSes allow systems to boot automatically. So look over your BIOS menu and see if it provides this feature.

An alternative suggestion would be to not shut down the system entirely, rather hibernate it. You can do this by -

```
rtcwake -s 43200 -m disk
```

This will hibernate your system right away and will wake after 12 hours. The parameter is in seconds. You can also specify a specific time by using the **-t** parameter.